# Do static arraylists lose what the contain?

Tags: java, arraylist, memory-leaks

I have a program and its processing rather large amounts of data. It is comparing one static string arraylist to another checking whether a string is contained in it.

But what happens is after processing lets say 40k+ strings it begins to fail on the checking. By fail I mean it begins to not recognize that a string already exists in the other?

Is there a reason for this or is the arraylist simply too large?

Thanks

EDIT

```
   for (int i = 0; i <  arraylist1.size(); i++) {
        boolean enter = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < arraylist2.size() && enter; x++) {
            if (arraylist1.get(i).getString().matches(arraylist2.get(x))) {
                enter = false;
            }
        }
        if (enter) {
       //do something
     }
  }
```

EDIT****

Off-topic to the question but using .equals() instead of .matches() improves the performance MASSIVELY.

Comment: Can you post some code with the resulting failure/exception?

Comment: You should be using HashSets anyway. This will run forever. And unless arraylist2 contains regular expressions you should have been using equals(), not matches().

Comment: Ideally, post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I dont get a failure or an exception but rather what seems to be an infinite loop. As I am printing out all my string after a while it starts to print out string that have already been added/

Comment: It may simply run too long if both lists have sizes around 40k. And don't use matches() for a simpl String compare - use equals(). This will increase your execution time by a factor of 10, easily.

Comment: Is there any reason why you use [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)? Do you have regular expressions in the 2nd list?

Comment: you know that `String#matches()` checks entire String right?

Comment: A factor of ten really? So should matches only be used in relation to a regex?

Comment: Yes - it is that costly due to repeated recalculation (compile) of a regex. equals()! And HashSet!!

Comment: A method that matches via a regular expression should only be used when you're supplying a regular expression. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: Even in this example a simple `break;` after `enter=false;` will improve performance a lot.

Comment: Even if in the loop it checks to see if enter is = to false?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I missed the `&& enter` bit, you are right that achieves the same end. The `break;` will be marginally more efficient as it doesn't do the boolean comparison each time around the loop but that difference will be very small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: no.

`ArrayLists` do not lose what is in them.

Your symptoms could be caused by a number of things, including threading/synchronization issues, subtle differences in the string, etc.

You should consider using a `HashSet` anyway though. It will make the "contains" check much much faster.

Using `HashSet` all your code above becomes:

```
List<String> list;
Set<String> set;

for (String str: list) {
   if (!set.contains(str)) {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Much simpler and incredibly faster.

If you do need to use lists you can do the same thing but having both collections as `List`, the API doesn't change but performance will.